# C#: Same "using" in multiple files

Tags: c#

This is probably not the smartest question, but can you reuse the same `using` directives in multiple C# files? I have several "typedefs" (`using foo = FooInc.FooProd.SomeClass;`) and would love not to have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> them in each file.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out-of-the box that will do that, but you can have Visual Studio generate usings for you on the fly as you code by right-clicking a type name underlined with a red squiggle and selecting "Resolve > using ...".

I find that if I do this, I don't often long for a feature that lets me auto copy/paste usings.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that with C# at this time - the directory must be present in any file you use... unless you make an automater for that.